# Check if an element already exist in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array
array =[['apple',23,1,20],['orange',12,10,10]]
How do i check if 10 exist in the above array ?I tried to use array.indexOf but it did not work well.Can someone help ?

Comment: Why didn't it work well?  Because you have nested arrays?

Answer (score 1):

1. **`.indexOf()`** will work, the problem is with the **`array`** variable.
2. **`array`** variable itself contains 2 different arrays.

Try the below code.

```
var array = [
    ['apple', 23, 1, 20],
    ['orange', 12, 10, 10]
];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {  //Iterate through arrays in array
    if (array[i].indexOf(10) > -1) {
        alert("Yep");
    } else {
        alert("nope");
    }
}
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/eqVbz/)

Answer (score 1):

in `ECMAScript 5` , there are two array methods `some` and `indexOf`

```
var search = 10 ;

var found  = a.some( function( v ) {
    return v.indexOf( search ) !== -1 ;
});

if ( found ) {
    alert( 'exists')
}
```

Comment: +1 interesting and look elegant.  Looping made easy in array, I have created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/eqVbz/2/.  one question does it support all browsers?  especially IE?

Comment: @user1671639 please check it in http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/

Comment: ie 9+, but there is a [shim available](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#Compatibility) for browsers that do not have it by default.
@rab, might want to check that v is an array before calling `indexOf` on it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be because:

- you have nested arrays
- Array.indexOf is not supported by all browsers

The following should work:

```
function includes(arrayOfArrays, item) {
    var array, i, j;
    for(i=0; i<arrayOfArrays.length; ++i) {
        array = arrayOfArrays[i];
        for(j=0; j<array.length; ++j) {
            if(array[j] === item) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to search in the array.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
var i,j;
var toFind = 10;
var array = new Array();
array = [['apple',23,1,20],['orange',12,10,10]]

for (i=0;i<array.length;i++)
{
   for(j=0;j<array[i].length;j++)
   {
       if(array[i][j] == toFind)
       document.write("element found <br/>");
   }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

where toFind  is the element or number that you want to find.